What kind of sentence is this? (and clause?)
"Conversations that change the world."
I recently learned about clauses and am a bit confused. "that change the world" is a dependent clause, yes?

It could serve as a title to an essay, but it is not a sentence.


conversations that change the world

isn't a sentence; it is a noun phrase.  Hence I've removed  the capital C and the fullstop.
The clause that change the world is a relative clause.  It describes conversations.
